# Using C++ libraries inside C#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I've written a C++ class which is built on OpenCV 3.1.

Currently I'm trying to import this library into C# using the CLR interface.  I can successfully call C++ methods from inside C#, but if I include any OpenCV related material in the C++, the C# app crashes saying it can't load the C++ DLL or its dependencies.

I've tried adding the OpenCV DLL as a reference in C# but VS2015 refuses to accept that (Mixing managed and unmanaged).

Anyone have some ideas or a tutorial that is trying to do something similar?  Better yet, specifically using custom C++ code thats built on OpenCV 3.1 inside C#?

If posting my code would help, I can do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Try Emgu CV, it's a .net wrapper.

Comment: I'm guessing you build your c++ lib with opencv linked dynamically? Does your c# app know when to look for opencv dlls? Try copying them to the folder where c# exe is. Or, possibly better, you can link opencv statically to your c++ library.